# how can i edit boot path in system configuration windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

Is it possible to edit windows boot path in system configeration on windows 10 ?

For some reason windows lost the OS's Path how can i edit it ?
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujkpq.png)

Comment: More context would be helpful.  For instance, where did this picture come from?

Comment: i founded what i've been looking for and it's a command `bcdedit`

Comment: Awesome! :)  Glad your problem is fixed.